# How to read values from properties file into Eclipse Product configuration file

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have one requirement in eclipse plugin development.

While creating eclipse product project in .product file, I have to read some values from properties file into Eclipse Product configuration file.

In product configuration file properties value and launching vm arguments, these values we have to read from .properties file.

I attached down 2 images, in that images build id is name and value is 1.0.1, so this 1.0.1 value i have to read from .properties file.

[image in launching tab vm arguments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LobJF.png)

[image configuration tab properties value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OsS0o.png)

Comment: What values in the .product file, exactly? Most values in this file are just copied to other files when you use 'Synchronize' and should be internationalized using the rules for those files.

Comment: thanks for replying on my issue

Comment: i have to internationalize in product configuration file properties value and launching arguments, these values we have to read from .properties file

Comment: It still isn't clear what values you are asking about. Edit your question and show us a example .product file and indicate exactly what needs i18n

Comment: thanks greg, now i posted 2 images also, please check it, in launching tab program arguments i want i18n and in configuration tab properties value i want i18n

Comment: Showing us two images with no values is not very helpful. If you mean you are specifying values for the config.ini and xxx.ini files I don't think there is any support for internationalizing values in these files.

Comment: hi greg now i changed images , in that images build id is 1.0.1, so this 1.0.1 value i have to read from .properties file, means i have to create one property file from there i have to read 1.0.1 value into vm arguments and configuration properties value ,this is my requirement

Comment: There is no support for that.